# Creating Windows shortcuts from Chrome bookmarks

Tags: windows, google-chrome, script, shortcuts, bookmarks

I have a very large number of bookmarks in Google Chrome. I want to transfer all of them to a windows folder, so that each bookmark will be a shortcut to a website (I want a list of shortcuts, just like any list of regular applications shortcuts). I also would like to preserve the bookmark's name.

I tried achieving my goal using the `Export bookmarks to HTML file` in the `Organize` menu inside the `Bookmark Manager`, but all I could do with it is save the links manually as `html` files, and they won't even save with their current bookmarks' names.

Comment: Open the HTML file and drag&drop every link to the desktop or a folder? Works in Firefox at least.

Comment: Do you want real Windows shortcuts (`.lnk`) or just `.url` files (Internet Explorer's bookmarks format)?

Comment: The Internet Shortcut extension (`.url`) is what I want. The drag&drop method works, but it would take me a while to do it manually. How can I speed things up? Also, I couldn't find out why I can't add description to the shortcuts after I've dropped them in the folder.

Comment: Given that `.url` files are simple text files, it should be easy to write a script that converts links in an HTML file to `.url` files. Do you have Cygwin?

Comment: Not at the moment, but I can install it.

Comment: The following works like a charm on OS X based on a Safari bookmarks file, I don't have the batch scripting skills or a Cygwin ready to create a proper Windows solution. `#/bin/bash BASEDIR='~/Desktop/bookmarks' ; IFS=$'\n' ; for line in $( grep -oi '<a .*</a>' "$1" ) ; do url=$( echo "$line" | sed 's|.*HREF="\(.*\)".*|\1|g' ) ; name=$( echo "$line" | sed 's|.*>\(.*\)</A>.*|\1|g;s|/||g' ) ; echo '[InternetShortcut]' > "$BASEDIR/$name.url" ; echo "URL=$url" >> "$BASEDIR/$name.url" ; done` Reads the HTML file passed as first argument; writes shortcuts to `~/Desktop/bookmarks`.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use Cygwin to run this script on Windows.

Comment: Take the entire thing, insert a linebreak after `#!/bin/bash`, change the value assigned to `BASEDIR` to an empty folder you prepared, and save as `htmltourl.sh`. Open the Cygwin shell, run `chmod +x /path/to/htmltourl.sh`, then `/path/to/htmltourl.sh /cygdrive/c/path/to/bookmarks.html`. If you could provide a Chrome bookmark HTML file, I could can adapt the script if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After searching the web for a while, I came to the conclusion that [there is no simple solution for this problem](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/m0Bopuvbo3s). There are different methods to save a link or a bookmark as a Windows URL shortcut, but there is no way to do it for multiple links / URLs at once.

Daniel Beck suggested an OS X / Safari bookmarks file based script, but I didn't manage to execute the script because I wasn't sure how to adapt it to Windows, even with Cygwin.

I realized the only way to achieve my goal is by using a script, so I posted a programming-specific question on Stack Overflow and asked for a script which would take the URLs from the links inside the `bookmarks.html` file and use them to create Windows URL shortcuts.

*Here is the question + the answer (it's a VBScript):*

[**Creating multiple Windows URL shortcuts from a bookmarks HTML file**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043989/creating-multiple-windows-url-shortcuts-from-a-bookmarks-html-file).

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I did:

1. I exported CHROME BOOKMARKS (also did this to my GOOGLE BOOKMARKS) as a single .html file. This can be done in Chrome through the bookmark manager's ORGANIZE | EXPORT dropdown.
2. I then opened my USER\Favorites folder. I don't use IE so it had all the default links IE comes with. I created a new folder called CHROME BOOKMARKS.
3. I opened IE and clicked the star shaped FAVORITES button. I pulled the ADD TO FAVORITES menu down and selected IMPORT AND EXPORT.

This launched an import wizard. I told it I was importing Favorites, and directed it to the .html file Chrome exported (#1), and told it to import to the CHROME BOOKMARKS folder I created (#2).

This created a .url file for each bookmark I had in Chrome which included both the BOOKMARKS BAR and the OTHER BOOKMARKS.

I tested and confirmed that a .URL file is launched in Chrome by double clicking or by drag and drop.

You can import the .URL files into Chrome, too. Leave the CHROME BOOKMARKS folder in your `User\Favorites` folder and then in Chrome click OTHER BOOKMARKS | IMPORTED FROM IE.  I think you can also do this in Chrome's Settings | USERS | Import Bookmarks and Settings, but I did not try this.

Comment: Does it keep Chrome's bookmarks folder structure?

Answer (score 1):

Outertech Linkman will handle the job easily. Import the bookmarks file and export your bookmarks to a custom favorites folder. It also supports Edge Chromium with some manual steps.